# why do i get Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React.js code Im fetching from an API and I m getting this error
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
PLEASE WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

> **Here's my fetch component in App.js**

```
    const App = () => {
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState({ loading: false })

  
  useEffect(() => {

    (async function() {
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        const res = await fetch('http://api.enye.tech/v1/challenge/records?limit=20&skip=0')
        const data  = await res.json();
        setRecords({ records: data})
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(data);
  
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })()
     
  }, []) 

      if(loading) {
        return <Preloader />
    }
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <SearchBar />
        <div className='container'>
          <Records loading={setLoading()} records={setRecords()} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

> **And this is where I'm passing in the fetched data as props**

```
const Records = ({ records, loading }) => {

    return (
        <div className={styles.p__container}>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-8">
                <div className="py-3">
                    {records.length} Records
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.p__grid}>
             {records.map(record => (
                 <RecordItem key={record.id} record={record} />
             ))
            }

        </div>
        <div className={styles.p__footer}>

        </div>
    </div>
    )
```

> **My integrated terminal shows no error but I get this error in my browser console**
> [image]

> **Im also trying to see if I can fetch just 20 profiles from the API instead of 100**

```
http://api.enye.tech/v1/challenge/records
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **error** is in the line

```
<Records loading={setLoading()} records={setRecords()} />
```

By writing `setLoading()` and `setRecords()` you are essentially changing the states `loading`, and `records`. This ensures a re-render, since **states are being changed**

I believe, you are trying to pass the current `loading` status and `records` array as props to component **Records**. To do so, you should pass the values like

```
<Records loading={loading} records={records} />
```

**That should clear out the `too many re-renders` error**

**Suggestion on `useState` usage**

You are initializing the states `loading` and `setRecords` in a different way than the way you are using it later.

For eg., you initialize `loading` as `{loading: false}` but later call `setLoading(false)`. You should initialize the `loading` state as a `boolean` state using

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

// example usage
setLoading(true);
```

Similarly, for `records`, you are initializing with an empty array `useState([])`, but later setting `records` **state** as an object using `setRecords({ records: data})`

You should use either one of the approaches

```
/** Approach 1 (Array typed) */
const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

// example usage
setRecords(data);

/** Approach 2 (Object typed) */
const [records, setRecords] = useState({records: []});

// example usage
setRecords({records: data});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely here, when you call `setLoading()` and `setRecords` on every render:

```
<Records loading={setLoading()} records={setRecords()} />
```

You probably just want to pass a the `loading` and `records` variables:

```
<Records loading={loading} records={records} />
```

Answer (score 0):

React has a property that whenever the value of states in a React component get updated, the component is re-rendered. Here you are passing the `setLoading()` and `setRecords()` as props to the `Records` component. You should pass `records` and `loading` instead. Every time `setLoading()` and `setRecords()` get updated, your component is re rendered and as a result an infinite loop of re rendering takes place.